# I am getting exception Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'studentRegistration' available as request attribute in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to spring. i am creating a project where registration is a basic requirement like any other project.But i am getting the Exception given below

```
Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'studentRegistration' available as request attribute
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'studentRegistration' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:144)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:154)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:422)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:84)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.studentRegistration_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(studentRegistration_jsp.java:565)
    at org.apache.jsp.studentRegistration_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(studentRegistration_jsp.java:419)
    at org.apache.jsp.studentRegistration_jsp._jspService(studentRegistration_jsp.java:189)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Jul 12, 2016 5:07:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/projectMonitoring] threw exception [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'studentRegistration' available as request attribute] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'studentRegistration' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:144)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:154)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:422)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:84)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.studentRegistration_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(studentRegistration_jsp.java:565)
    at org.apache.jsp.studentRegistration_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(studentRegistration_jsp.java:419)
    at org.apache.jsp.studentRegistration_jsp._jspService(studentRegistration_jsp.java:189)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I know this exception is very common and lot of people replied to this but any of the solution did not worked for me.I also tried to run the ".war" file of previously created project of same category but they are also showing the same exception.At last i am posting this question here.
This is my model

```
package edu.projectMonitoring.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="studentdetail")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @Column(name="emailId")
    String email;
    @Column(name="name")
    String name;
    @Column(name="Class")
    String clas;
    @Column(name="enrollementNo")
    String enrollment;
    @Column(name="password")
    String password;
    @Column(name="course")
    String course;
    @Column(name="contactNo")
    String contactNo;
    @Column(name="status")
    String status;



    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getClas() {
        return clas;
    }

    public String getEnrollment() {
        return enrollment;
    }
    public void setEnrollment(String enrollment) {
        this.enrollment = enrollment;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getCourse() {
        return course;
    }
    public void setCourse() {
        this.course = course;

    }
    public String getContactNo() {
        return contactNo;
    }
    public void setContactNo(String contactNo) {
        this.contactNo = contactNo;
    }

    public void setClas(String clas) {
        this.clas = clas;
    }
    public void setCourse(String course) {
        this.course = course;
    }



}
```

This is my controller

```
package edu.projectMonitoring.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import edu.projectMonitoring.model.Student;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/studentRegistration")
public class StudentRegistration {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String viewRegistration(Map<String, Object> model) {
    Student registerForm = new Student();
    model.put("studentRegistration", registerForm);
    List<String> courseList = new ArrayList<String>();
    courseList.add("Developer");
    courseList.add("Designer");
    courseList.add("IT Manager");
    model.put("courseList", courseList);
    return "studentRegistration";
    }
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processRegistration(@ModelAttribute("studentRegistration") Student registerForm,
    Map<String, Object> model) {
    // implement your own registration logic here...
    // for testing purpose:
    /*System.out.println("username: " + user.getUsername());
    System.out.println("password: " + user.getPassword());
    System.out.println("email: " + user.getEmail());
    System.out.println("birth date: " + user.getBirthDate());
    System.out.println("profession: " + user.getProfession());
*/  return "index";
    }

}
```

this is my view

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
    <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <%--  <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" />" rel="stylesheet"> --%>
    <spring:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" var="mainCss" /> 
    <link href="${mainCss}" rel="stylesheet" />
   <!--  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet"> -->
    <spring:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap-cerulean.min.css" var="cerulonCss" /> 
    <link href="${cerulonCss}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <spring:url value="/resources/css/charisma-app.css" var="charismaCss" /> 
    <link href="${charismaCss}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <spring:url value="/resources/css/animate.min.css" var="animateCss" /> 
    <link href="${animateCss}" rel="stylesheet" />
     <spring:url value="/resources/css/custom.css" var="customCss" /> 
    <link href="${customCss}" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<div>
<form:form action="studentRegistration" method="post" commandName="studentRegistration" class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><spring:message code="student.name"/></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <form:input path="name" class="form-control"  placeholder="Name"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="course" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><spring:message code="student.course"/></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <form:select path="course" items="${courseList}" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="clas" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><spring:message code="student.class"/></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <form:select path="clas" items="${classList}" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="enrollement" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><spring:message code="student.enrollement"/></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <form:input path="enrollement" class="form-control"  placeholder="Enrollement Number"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="contactNo" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><spring:message code="student.enrollement"/></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <form:input path="contactNo" class="form-control"  placeholder="Contact Number"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><spring:message code="student.enrollement"/></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <form:input path="email" class="form-control"  placeholder="Email"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><spring:message code="student.enrollement"/></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <form:password path="password" class="form-control"  placeholder="Password"/>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
    </div>
  </div>


</form:form>
</div>
<!-- JavaScript Files Starts-->
<spring:url value="/resources/js/jquery-1.12.2.min.js" var="jqueryJs" />
<spring:url value="/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js" var="bootstrapJs" />
<spring:url value="/resources/js/jquery.cookie.js" var="cookieJs" />
<spring:url value="/resources/js/charisma.js" var="charJs" />

<script src="${jqueryJs}"></script>
<script src="${bootstrapJs}"></script>
<script src="${cookieJs}"></script>
<script src="${charJs}"></script>

<!-- JavaScript Files Ends-->
</body>
</html>
```

And at last this is my pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.hari</groupId>
  <artifactId>springBasics</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>springBasics Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>

      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
   <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
   </dependency>

   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-annotations -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
</dependency>

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-commons-annotations -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.21</version>
</dependency>



  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>projectMonitoring</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Please help to get out of this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: once try to add dummy values for the registerForm obj of class Student. Like the name, email. And make your all member variable private in your Student class to implement encapsulation properly.

Comment: i did the changes but id didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the problem is i am requesting the page `http://localhost:8080/projectMonitoring/studentRegistration.jsp` 
in this manner.That is  i am requesting studentRegistration.jsp but by controller is created to handle the mapping name "studentRegistration"

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/studentRegistration")
```

therefore it is showing the exception.
But when i request the page with the name

```
http://localhost:8080/projectMonitoring/studentRegistration
```

Then it executed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approach to see whether you are still facing the error

My assumption: you're displaying actual jsp on the browser with a html extension.

1. Modify your StudentRegistration.java controller slightly, .e.g.

   ```
   @Controller
   public class StudentRegistration {

   @RequestMapping(value = "/studentRegistration", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String viewRegistration(Map<String, Object> model) {
       Student registerForm = new Student();
       model.put("studentRegistration", registerForm);
       List<String> courseList = new ArrayList<String>();
       courseList.add("Developer");
       courseList.add("Designer");
       courseList.add("IT Manager");
       model.put("courseList", courseList);
       return "studentRegistration";
   }

   @RequestMapping((value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String processRegistration(@Valid Student registerForm, Map<String, Object> model, BindingResult result) {   
       if (result.hasErrors()) {
           return "error";
       } 
       else {
            //Do your student registeration process
           ...
           return "index";
       }
   }}
   ```

   2. Modify your JSP on the form tag

`<form:form action="index.html" method="post" commandName="studentRegistration" class="form-horizontal">`

Comment: no, i am displaying the actual jsp with jsp extension.

Answer (score 0):

1. The recommended practice is not to expose your underlying technology
   therefore when you have `Jsp` implementation then it is better to
   mask into something simple like you help.jsp as help.html. You can
   achieve this using  bean configuration like

   `

   `@Bean
   public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
           InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
           resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
           resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
           resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
           return resolver;
       }`

`

or xml configuration

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

2. When you have for e.g. an **index.jsp** file with the follwoing link and it is clicked, the controller below will pick up.

`<a href="help.html" class="space"><spring:message code="top.reviews" />`

3. The controller as below. **Note:** value '/help' in the RequestMapping should match the help.html without extension .html

   `@RequestMapping(value = "/help", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String getHelpPage(Map model, Locale loc) {

       model.put("singleReport", new YourUserForm());
       return "help";
   }`